# Excel menu bar freeze after running code. unfreeze after right mouse click

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a form with a button to download a sheet from intranet and populate this destination sheet with data from the source sheet. This part works: the data is populated, form unloads, script stops and I've got my destination sheet as active screen.
Now comes the problem: I can select cells, but can't use any functions in Excel, can't push any buttons like File, Home or Save on the quick access ribbon. Pushing `ESC` doesn't help. The only thing that unfreezes Excel is pushing right mouse button somewhere in a random cell. It 'unlocks' excel and I can go the File menu. I don't know where to look. I think it's something small but can't figure out what is it.

**This is the code** (the jump is used for single or multi items. If it's for 1 item I skip the loop. Maybe there is a better option for this?):

```
Private Sub genbutton_Click()
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim startsheet As String
    startsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    roww = ActiveCell.Row

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'search for column in source sheet
    kolommaint = kolomnaam2("Maintenance Plan")
    kolomfloc = kolomnaam2("Functional Location")
    kolomdescrip = kolomnaam2("Maintenance item description")
    kolomequip = kolomnaam2("Equipment")

    'find last row on data source page
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, kolommaint).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set destinationsheet = Workbooks.Open("http:// sheet on intranet.xlsm")

    'find first data row on destination sheet
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = "Action"
    With destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
            datarij = ActiveCell.Row + 1
        End If
    End With
    'make a jump to avoid loop if only 1 item is needed
    If callsingle.Value = True Then
        i = roww

        If Source.Range(kolommaint & i).Value = "" Then
            GoTo verdergaan
        End If
        GoTo jump
    End If

    For i = eerstedatarij To lastrow

jump:
        'skip row if empty
        If Source.Rows(i).Hidden = True Then
            GoTo verdergaan
        End If

        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("A" & datarij).Value = "Release Call"
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("B" & datarij).Value = Source.Range(kolommaint & i).Value
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("C" & datarij).Value = "PM"
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("E" & datarij).Value = Source.Range(kolomdescrip & i).Value
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("F" & datarij).Value = Source.Range(kolomdescrip & i).Value
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("G" & datarij).Value = Source.Range(kolomfloc & i).Value
        destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("H" & datarij).Value = Source.Range(kolomequip & i).Value

        datarij = datarij + 1

        'make jump if single item is used
        If callsingle.Value = True Then
            GoTo jump2
        End If

verdergaan:
    Next i
jump2:

    destinationsheet.Sheets("Data input").Range("A13").Select

    Set Source = Nothing
    Set destinationsheet= Nothing

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

I'm using the code below to unfreeze excel for now:

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
 Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
 Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10

 Public Sub RightDown()
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't "Jump" into a For loop. Try to avoid using GoTo, except for error handling. If you want to stop a For loop, just use "Exit For".

Comment: i made a type in the code comment. its more a jump for not getting into the loop. but thanks for the comment, i'm going to experiment with Exit For. i use jumps for more functions but never encountering problems with frozen screens.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with freeze on Excel functions. I believe that it's caused by a focus bug when opening worksheet with "Worksheets.Open"

The problem appeared when having a userform visible when executing "Worksheets.Open". I had to hide the userform first and then open the worksheet to avoid the freeze problem.

The code that causes the freeze on excel functions:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
  Dim retVal As Integer
  Dim fDialog As FileDialog
  Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
  retVal = fDialog.Show()

  If retVal = -1 Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Me.Hide   ' Hiding my userform
  End If
End Sub
```

But I found a solution to the freeze with hide and show the worksheet window.

```
  Dim aWorkbook As Workbook
  Set aWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
  aWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
  aWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

Then it worked. The only downside is that changing the visibility puts the worksheet in a changed state. If it is possible it would be better just to hide the userform before opening the workbook.